# jQuery hide() on click function does not work if using HTML5 data attribute in absolute position

Tags: jquery, html, hide, show

The problem is with `fa-close` icon and jquery `hide()` function. If i am using simple html atributes, than everything works fine, but if i am using HTML5 `data` attribute, than code just does not work.

How can i hide both `#dialogbox` and `#message` on `.fa-close` click which displayed in `#message` ? I mean, that i need to hide both divs **ONLY** when clicked on `.fa-close`.I am banging my head because of this...

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialogbox"></div>
<div id="message"></div>

<div class="box">
   <div data-category="#test" class="hoveris">OPEN</div>
</div>

<div id="test" class="item">some text <i class="fa fa-close"></i></div>
```

**CSS**

```
#dialogbox { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8); display:none; }

#message { position:absolute; margin:auto; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; width:70%; height:70%; background:#fff; display:none; }

.box { float:left; margin:0; padding:30px; background:green; color:#fff; cursor:pointer; }

.item { display:none; }
```

**JS**

```
$('.box').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).find('.hoveris').data('category');
  var message = $(id).html();
  $("#message").html(message).show();
  $('#dialogbox').show();
});


$("#dialogbox").click(function () {
   $('#dialogbox, #message').hide();
});

$("#message .fa-close").click(function(){ // NOT WORKING
   $("#dialogbox, #message").hide();
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/munej585/4/)

Sorry for bad english, and thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some debugging I've missed the obvious.

```
$("#message").on('click', '.fa-close', function(){
    $("#dialogbox, #message").hide();
});
```

You are dynamically changing the content of the message div therefore the element does not exist when you bind the click event. Therefore you use the `on` callback onto an existing element so the event can later be caught.

Comment: Well, i need to hide ``#dialogbox`` and ``#message`` only if ``.fa-close`` is clicked. Your way hides everything even if i am clicking on ``#message``

Comment: Then just remove the `#message` from the selector? Edited.

Comment: Nope. Look at jsfiddle. Thats a problem with that.

Comment: Atlast. 3-4 hours of head banging. I didnt even thought about ``.on``. Thanks :)